# AWS IoT Core and Mobile SDK - Cache Capacity and Cache Control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-sdk-ios, aws-sdk-android

How does AWS IoT SDK for Things or for Mobile(Android/iOS) stores data to sync later when network is not present or device(Thing/Mobile) is not connected to internet.
Is there a Storage Manager and Sync Manager concept while communicating between AWS IoT SDK and Cloud, as it seems to be needed when device is not connected to internet? If there is, then what is the limit of such storage?

Have gone through the concept of Persistence Sessions.

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT SDK for android stores messages to be published while the client is offline in an in-memory queue whose size is a configurable property. The total size of the queue is limited to the amount of memory allocated to the process :

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-iot/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/iot/AWSIotMqttManager.java#L125